# Play GIF image in glide once

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-glide

I'm trying to find how can I set a GIF image in image button and set it to play only once.

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        var ib_main_home = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.ds);
        Glide.With(this).AsGif()
 .Load(Resource.Mipmap.giphy)
 .Into(ib_main_home);
```

Answer (score 8):

Please try to add a `RequestListener`. And set the loop count in `OnResourceReady()`.
For example:

```
Glide.With(this).AsGif().Load(Resource.Mipmap.giphy).Listener(new MyRequestListener()).Into(ib_main_home);
```

And the `RequestListener`:

```
public class MyRequestListener :Java.Lang.Object, IRequestListener
{
    public bool OnLoadFailed(GlideException p0, Java.Lang.Object p1, ITarget p2, bool p3)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool OnResourceReady(Java.Lang.Object p0, Java.Lang.Object p1, ITarget p2, DataSource p3, bool p4)
    {
        if (p0 is GifDrawable)
        {
            ((GifDrawable)p0).SetLoopCount(1);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please check the following link for more information:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1706#issuecomment-282827419

Comment: Could you please share java equivalent ?

Comment: it should be nearly identical as Xamarin is built to be a thin wrapper over the Android SDK

Comment: @Arjun this post should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645199/android-gif-animation-cycle-complete-listener

Answer (score 8):

Java version to the Billy's answer to load gif into image view and control how many loops you want:

```
Glide.with(this)
            .asGif()
            .load(R.raw.onboarding_layers) //Your gif resource
            .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
            .listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    resource.setLoopCount(1);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.layer_icons));
```

Comment: what is `RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` for?