# Android animation to draw alphabet

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, graphics

I am stuck at the animation part which is kinda tough for me, I need to draw [this green sign like this](https://streamable.com/ippq1c). I tried this [Github guide](https://github.com/pratikishere/Androideverywhere-Resources/wiki/Android-Curved-Motion-or-Path-Animation) achieve my requirement but with using `Path` i can only move view with the help of coordinates and i am far from the result i need. I am not sure where to start to get the desired result from animation. I am avoiding embeded `GIF` and any heavy library to get my result. Please help in this kind of animation, I know it's pretty tough to get this kind of animation via code.

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks

If above video link is not working please check this : [Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RSETe6emyLW_-aFZhCcsFc4ptVSztPU2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://streamable.com/ippq1c is broken

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Working for me

Comment: @androidXP It doesn't comply with Indian standards of .com compliance. I tried with proxy servers as well but no luck. If it is working for you, attach that image in the question.

Comment: Make the drive link public we need access...

Comment: @PraveenSP It's public already. Please check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great tool for creating animating vectors like this.
https://shapeshifter.design/ I have created your example there and I will try to explain how in next few steps.

In bottom left corner next to File, Import and Export click to add window to add new Path. After path is added select it and navigate to pathData field. First we will start with animated part, add this to pathData

```
M 4 6 L 22 2 L 2 22 L 19.5 3.5 L 4 6
```

You can check more information about M, L, Z commands here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42138513/13481732

Also set fill color to whatever you need.

In the bottom left corner for recently created path or in top right corner next to path name, select stopwatch and add pathData animation.

For first animation set

```
startTime = 0
endTime = 100 //CHANGE THIS BASE ON YOUR NEEDS
interpolator = Linear
fromValue = M 4 6 L 4 6 L 4 6 Z
toValue = M 4 6 L 22 2 L 19 3.5 Z
```

Then add another animation (There is + sign on added pathData animation in bottom left corner) and set next values

```
startTime = 100 //CHANGE THIS BASE ON YOUR NEEDS
endTime = 200 //CHANGE THIS BASE ON YOUR NEEDS
interpolator = Linear
fromValue = M 4 6 L 22 2 L 19 3.5 Z M 22 2 L 22 2 L 19 3.5 Z
toValue = M 4 6 L 22 2 L 19 3.5 Z M 22 2 L 2 22 L 19 3.5 Z
```

Then for white parts add two new paths. In top set pathData to this:

```
M 9 7.5 L 11.5 11 L 12.5 10 L 10.5 7.5 Z
```

In bottom set pathData to this:

```
M 13 12.5 L 15.5 15.5 L 17 15.5 L 14 11.5 Z
```

To change background color, in bottom left corner select vector and then in field canvasColor set your background Color.

After you are done you can export it as Animated Vector Drawable and add it to your project. When you add generated .xml file to project open it and change width and height.

This is an example how to start animation:

```
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
if( drawable instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable ) {
    AnimatedVectorDrawable animation = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) drawable;
    animation.start();
}
```

Comment: I can't get the result as i need with `Path`

Comment: @Ritu this answer is the 'Option 1' that the author Abhishek mentioned, and if you set the right path(include fromValue, toValue, color , alpha, and so on), you can export it to SVG file, or Vector Drawable file, then you can load the animation path xml file with 'AnimatedVectorDrawable'. And you can import the 'Demo' by File-->Demo to study how to get the right path at the tool Website https://shapeshifter.design/.

Comment: @Hai-YangLi as mentioned in Question she already tried GIF and GIF can't give you smooth and quality transaction. We need to use heavy GIF to get quality of animation which increase size of app and also animation might lag in older devices.

Comment: @apollo How did you figure out the animation `fromValue` to `toValue` in both animation paths?

Comment: @androidXP There is a requirement that `fromValue` and `toValue` needs to have same number and types of drawing commands. So in first animation path i knew that i will need to have 3 points in `fromValue` and `toValue` paths. As you can see in `fromValue = M 4 6 L 4 6 L 4 6 Z` points are starting from same coordinate 4(x) 6(y) and in `toValue = M 4 6 L 22 2 L 19 3.5 Z` I am moving second and third point to final path coordinates. In second animation i am doing the same logic, only difference is that final path of animation 1 is included in `fromValue` and `toValue` path of second animation.

Comment: @androidXP It was not that easy to explain it so i hope my previous comment was helpful. Also if you do not have much experience with this i recommend you to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgbl34me3kk)

Comment: @Apollo thanks for the explanation. it really help me

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not able to use `Path` because `Path` moves an object from one place to another to produce animation. Whereas your video is creating an object(the Green section) as part of the animation. So you have two options.

**Option 1**
Create an SVG and add it as an animated vector drawable within your code. 
You can use an online tool to create SVG from your video. And then add that SVG into your `drawables` and create a `pathmorph` XML to change the color from black to green. Example on `[Android Developer Website][1]`

Usually it will involve two steps

Step 1: Get SVG file for your animation using a [video to SVG converter](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg).

Step 2: Change color of your SVG Path from black to green. You can read some [sample code for that](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/jaredrummler/android/widget/AnimatedSvgView.java). Or you can use the [AnimatedSVGview](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView) library for dynamically adding green color to your SVG.

**Option 2**
An easier way is to convert this video to Gif and then just display it using Glide.

`ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.image_gif).into(imageView);`

Comment: can you please show some kind of example of option 1. For Option 2 i already mentioned that i don't want to use GIF because it bit heavy for device

Comment: Firstly, Glide is not very heavy. You can do a memory analysis. Secondly, Glide allows you multiple image formats from both your device as well as from servers. So once you start developing the app further and need to load images from a URL, you will need Glide. I will add more details to my answer anyway.

Comment: With Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.image_gif).into(imageView); gif plays fine. but repeats again and again.

After adding .asGif(), GIF stops appearing only. I need to make it stop after it plays once, so I am trying to attach listener (for which .asGif() is important) to it like:

Glide.with(this).asGif().load(getDrawable(R.drawable.a)).listener(new GifEndListener()).into(imageView);

I have GifEndListener implemented like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868708/5254732

Comment: @Rohit - Why don't you ask a new question and add a link here. I will see if I can answer. Please don't forget to add your code to the question.